# Amazon AMI tomcat7 tomcat-users.xml: command not found

Tags: linux, tomcat, amazon-web-services, tomcat7, amazon-ami

I've created the free AMI linux instance on the amazon ec2. I'm trying to setup tomcat7, but seem to have run into an issue setting up an admin user to tomcat7. I've installed the following.

> sudo yum install tomcat7-webapps tomcat7-docs-webapp
>   tomcat7-admin-webapps

When I try to access the xml using the following command.

> sudo /etc/tomcat7/tomcat-users.xml

I receive the following error, sudo: /etc/tomcat7/tomcat-users.xml: command not found

I admit, I'm a complete newbie to linux, so I'm not sure if I'm missing something. Would anybody happen to know what I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sudo` only escalates privs. You didn't not provide a command to use sudo with. Maybe you intended to do this

```
sudo vi /etc/tomcat7/tomcat-users.xml
```

Comment: Your absolutely correct. I just stumbled on this about 10mins ago after reading this handy article, http://www.howtogeek.com/102468/a-beginners-guide-to-editing-text-files-with-vi/ I'm a complete newbie to linux. Thanks for your help.